# Disable/Enable double logo in beamer

Tags: beamer, logos

I am trying to disable the double logo at specific frames, where an image can overlap with the right-hand-side logo and then enable it back again.

My code is

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{doublelogo}%Double logo after a certain slide
\setboolean{doublelogo}{true}
\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{doublelogo}}{
    \includegraphics[width=0.8cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}}{}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8cm,keepaspectratio]{demokritos-logo.jpg}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}hjkl;
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
    \item Why : \uncover<1->{\begin{enumerate}
                          \item $Si,Ge$
                          \item Yes
                          \item No
                         \end{enumerate}}
      \item \uncover<2->{\setboolean{doublelogo}{false}\begin{enumerate}
                          \item non-Rutherford
                          \item $(p,\alpha)$
                         \end{enumerate}}
      \item Blue
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{crossSections}\\
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{alphaBG}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and my output is

[image]

Any idea on how to make it work or any other advice for preventing the right-hand-side logo from overlapping with a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that logo is placed in the document as a part of each frame and you cannot modify it from within the frame. However you can "divide" the frame into two. Also you do not need the `\uncover`, just write `< >`.

Use the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\logo{%
  \makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8cm,keepaspectratio]{noimage}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=0.8cm,keepaspectratio]{noimage}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=fr:1]
% HERE I defined, that only the items with <1> (or without a number) from this frame will show up
% I also labeled this frame "fr:1" for later use
  hjkl;
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Why :
          \begin{enumerate}
            \item $Si,Ge$
            \item Yes
            \item No
          \end{enumerate}
        \item<2->
          \begin{enumerate}
            \item non-Rutherford
            \item $(p,\alpha)$
          \end{enumerate}}
        \item Blue
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \only<1->{\rule{\linewidth}{\linewidth}}\\ % HERE by writing \only I just wanted to emphasize the difference between both frames
      \only<2->{\rule{\linewidth}{\linewidth}}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

{ % start of frames with no logo
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{} % HERE I set logo to nothing
\againframe<2->{fr:1} % HERE I use the 2nd and every other part of "fr:1"
} % end of frames with no logo
% these brackets are important because otherwise the no-logo style will apply to the rest of your document

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that I want only the right logo to disappear, not both of them...Is this achievable?

Comment: @Thanos Sure! Just instead of `\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}` put there `\setbeamertemplate{logo}{\makebox[0.99\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.8cm,keepaspectratio]{noimage}\hfill}}` - well the first part (left logo). Because this command redefines the logo to whatever you want, e.g. no logo or only left logo.